# Focus on an anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I have some HTML that looks something like this:

```
            <div id="zoomed" style="display:none; position:absolute;">
            <a href="#" alt="close" id="closeLink" onclick="closeZoom();" tabindex="2"><img alt="close" style="border-style:none" class="close" id="closeButton" src="Images/trans.png"/></a>
            <div class="zoomParent">
            <table>
                <tbody data-bind="with: currentFactor">
                    <tr><td class="zIngHeader" colspan="3">
                    <span data-bind="text: FactorName"></span>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="zMin" data-bind="text: formatValues(Min)"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" data-bind="value: currentValue" class="channel" onkeydown="EnterToTabHack(event);" tabindex="1"/></td>
                        <td class="zMax" data-bind="text: formatValues(Max)"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td colspan="3" class="graphCell" data-bind="animateColor: $root.statusColor"><div id="zoomPlot" class="zoomPlotStyle"></div></td></tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Now, when you are in the text box and you hit the tab key, the anchor tags gets focus, so if you immediately hit enter, you'll run the function closeZoom(). This works fine.

What I want to do is have so if you are in the textbox and you hit enter, it will behave the same way as if you hit tab. So I have a function to do this:

```
    function EnterToTabHack(event) {
        if ((event.which && event.which == 13) || (event.keyCode && event.keyCode == 13)) {
            $(".channel").blur();
            $("#closeLink").focus();
        }
    }
```

The blur part works fine, the value in the textbox gets written back to my viewmodel as I wanted, but the focus doesn't end up on my link. Hitting enter twice *should* accept the value in the textbox (which is does) and then close the window (it doesn't).

Any idea what might be wrong here? I see no error messages, but clearly the focus isn't on the anchor link like it would be if I hit tab (note: just blurring doesn't seem to do it either).

**Edit:** I've added a little more of the html because it may, or may not, be relevant. In particular, I'm using KnockoutJS for data binding and I think that is making it impossible to use the type of jQuery bindings (of events) that several people have suggested, or at least, if I were to use them, I'd have to rebind then every time "currentFactor" changed because *I think* what knockout is doing is destroying everything in the body of the table and recreating it when that part changes.

**Another Edit:** First, a really big thanks to everybody who has tried to help so far! I really appreciate you taking the time to take a look at this.

I played around and put together a JS Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/sUh8G/4/

At first I was confused because, of course, it worked fine! Then I added the styles for the img and it seems that using sprites this way is what breaks it. If you remove all the img styles from the css, it works fine. With them, I can't focus it programmatically.

Anybody seen anything like that before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok here is a simplified fiddle, I used the js code from one of the other answers. The focus seems to work on my current browser FF 14

http://jsfiddle.net/ZKYc3/

Here is a version that works in FF 14

http://jsfiddle.net/ZKYc3/2/  this one has a alert when the closelInk is clicked. Double enter triggers the alert. Perhaps all you need to do is take the event handling out of the html and leave it up to jquery to take care of

Update: see http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html

I think you should probably follow that since you are using knockout

Updated fiddle working

http://jsfiddle.net/sUh8G/5/

Comment: Your fiddle works, but it's using jQuery to wire up the keypress event. This doesn't seem to work with knockoutjs when I use a with clause (it seems reevaluating the with clause removes all the jQuery wired events).

Comment: your original code works if you add an alt tag to the image (in fiddle at least) except it works right away as soon as you hit enter once

Comment: @MattBurland the only way I have made it work is changing the original onkeydown to onkeyup for the input tag. Anything else would trigger the click event 1 click too early or not at all. This is without binding the events using jquery to avoid conflict

Comment: @MattBurland see my update, I think we been doing the wrong approach

Comment: I'd tried event binding with knockout before and I have the same problem. I don't think the problem is getting the event to fire (either event binding with KO, onkeydown/up/press or jQuery binding done when the current item changes all fire). The problem is that the focus doesn't want to go to my anchor tag for some reason.

Comment: @MattBurland on my fiddle the focus goes there, did you add an alt tag to the image?

Comment: See my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sUh8G/4/ I think the problem is actually coming from the styles applied to the image. If I remove the image styles, it works exactly like your fiddle. Really weird!

Comment: @MattBurland http://jsfiddle.net/sUh8G/5/ see this fiddle, it works, you should style the anchor and not the image. I updated my answer with this as well

Comment: I think that's very, very close to the answer. Your fiddle works great in both FF and IE9, so I made similar adjustments to my actual project and it works in FF, but in IE9 the focus ends up somewhere else. I'll have to investigate further to figure out what's different between my project and the fiddle, but for now, I'm gonna mark your answers as correct and I'll post a separate question if I'm still stuck with my specific project (hopefully once I've figured out what the difference is). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is set the focus to `#closeLink`

```
$('.channel').on('keydown', function(e) {
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if(code == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#closeLink').focus();
    }
});
```

You don't have to set the `onkeydown="EnterToTabHack(event);"` in the input. The outline does not always show around the URL but the function will `focus()` the link. The `preventDefault` is because the link would trigger when the `keyup` happens.

Answer (score 1):

I would take the onclick and onkeydown out of your html elements...

```
<a href="#" id="closeLink" tabindex="2"><img class="close" style="border-style:none" id="closeButton" src="Images/trans.png"/></a>

<input type="text" data-bind="value: currentValue" class="channel" tabindex="1"/>
```

and use jquery to wire up these events...

```
$(function(){
    $('#closeLink').click(closeZoom);

    $('.channel').keypress(function(e){
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        if(code == 13) { //Enter keycode
           $(".channel").blur();
           $("#closeLink").focus();
        }
    });
});
```

I used keypress here instead of keydown, because keydown will focus the link, and then keyup will fire the click event. If this is the behavior you want, use keydown. Otherwise, keypress will set the focus to the link, and the second enter press will fire the click event.

Comment: Actually I originally tried wiring up using jQuery, but it doesn't play nice with knockoutjs when using a "with" clause. Changing the item bound by with causing knockout to recreate everything and lose the event wiring.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. What about using jQuery `.on('keypress', function)` instead of `.keypress(function)`? Maybe include the ko code as well?

Answer (score 1):

```
function EnterToTabHack(event) {
        if ((event.which && event.which == 13) || (event.keyCode && event.keyCode == 13)) {
            $(".channel").blur();
        }
    }    

$(".channel").blur(function() {
      $("#closeLink").focus();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

use the keyup event

```
<a href="#" id="closeLink" onclick="closeZoom();" tabindex="2" ><img alt='testtesttest' class="close" style="border-style:none" id="closeButton" src="Images/trans.png"/></a>

<input type="text" data-bind="value: currentValue" class="channel" onkeyup="EnterToTabHack(event);" tabindex="1"/>
```

then the js

```
function EnterToTabHack(event) {   
        if ((event.which && event.which == 13) || (event.keyCode && event.keyCode == 13)) {        
            $("#closeLink").focus();
        }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/KcRyV/

Answer (score 0):

This looks fine, but your last line`$("#closeLink").focus();`

should be changed to this:`$("#closeLink").click();`

Comment: but he doesn't want to click on it. He jsut wnat it to have the focus so when he hit enter again it would trigger the closeZoom()

Comment: @cheezSammich: Huangism is correct. I don't want to automatically click it, I just want it highlighted so the next enter will close it. This gives the user the chance to see what happened and change the value if they want. If they are happy with the result, they can just mash the enter button twice and they are done.