# how to focus an "anchor" element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make an `a` element to gain focus, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open the link.

`<a id='link'>test</a>`

I use `$("#link").focus()`, but it doesn't work.

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you show the HTML?

Comment: we need to see your whole code.. you should be making something wrong somewhere.. otherwise check this fiddle.. focus() on anchor works fine http://jsfiddle.net/88C5V/

Comment: you can put autofocus attribute in your anchor element..html5 way

Comment: I am sorry, I misuse `focusin`, I just change to use `focus`, it works, thx.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Focus on an anchor tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11958021/focus-on-an-anchor-tag)

Comment: The answer is part of the question.  It was a typo in code.  The whole post should be deleted.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/RLJ5r/1/

Works fine.

HTML:

```
<a href="http://google.com" id="link">test</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#link").focus();
```

Comment: Do not forget the href attribute, even if it's only "#". Without it, the focus method won't work

Comment: In native JS:
`
var elem = document.getElementById('link');
elem.focus();
`

And as mentioned in the comment above, remember that href attribute must be present.